# keycode value for less than(<) button in android virtual keyboard can be used by Robotium(automation)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, robotium, keycode

Through `Robotium(solo.sendKey method)`, i was able to click on comma(,) button with on android virtual keyboard. how can do this for lessthan(<) button. what is the keycode value for this and how can i use through `Robotium`.

the keycode value used for comma(,) is '55'

Answer (score 0):

Use [ascii](http://ascii.cl/) value 60 for less than

```
solo.sendKey(60);
```

Comment: thanks for reply Fahim. solo.sendKey(60) is not working, an empty space is printing(in notepad). i can print comma(,) by using solo.sendKey(55). in [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) the keycode value for comma is 55. But what may be the value for lessthan. Does it requires any key combination click?